# UK Royal Mail PAF address finder via postcode alternatives?

Tags: postal-code, paf

We need an address finder (premise level) based on postcode. We have a budget of 40k for this. But I have been assigned to find some cheaper alternatives for Royal mail PAF database. Is Google any good to find premise level address when you send full postcode. Any recommendation over Royal Mail PAF file. Any web services out there for this to accomplish? Please share your knowledge.

Cheers,
Naren

Answer (score 1):

We use [products from AFD](http://www.afd.co.uk/products.asp) for this, they work well for us.

Edit just saw [Best way to geocode UK postcode with Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832909/best-way-to-geocode-uk-postcode-with-google-maps-api) on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

I work as the integrations specialist for Postcode Anywhere (we are one of the leading Royal Mail PAF resellers). Address capture doesn’t have to be expensive – and you don’t have to sacrifice reliability for an affordable service. Postcode Anywhere can be licensed either on a simple credit pack based system or on an annual basis, and you can be up and running in 10 minutes using our JavaScript client. If you are looking to create a more bespoke integration we also have an array of web services and code samples to help you.

If you want to have a play around with the service to see what you think we will be more than happy to provide you with a free trial. A full run-down of all of our products and services can be found here: http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/products.

Comment: +1 for Postcode Anywhere. I've used it before on several projects now, it comes highly recommended. There may be other solutions; in fact, there definitely are - but Postcode Anywhere I've found to be the best I've had to work with so far.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Very useful information. Is there any way that I can contact you to discuss further.

Comment: +1 for Postcode Anywhere, used them a while back, very simple to get up and running

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the government has said that PAF data should be made free[1]. I'm painfully aware of the **almost extortionate nature** that Royal Mail operate.

Having worked with Royal Mail PAF API,  I known a 'friend' (wink wink) that created a class wrapper around the APIs. This 'friend' of mine built a custom Importer that automatically ripped all the PAF data into a MS SQL database. Post the data import, he no longer needs to renew he's licences because he is no longer using PAF data.

This may be something you could do also, buy the data one time an import it.

As for data changes, you can buy perhaps every few years e.g. 2-3 years and do a update of your existing data.

[1] **Damn It!** guess I was wrong, http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2010/jan/22/postcode-petition-fails-blocked-number-ten

Answer (score 0):

I work for [CraftyClicks](http://www.craftyclicks.co.uk).

There are a few PAF resellers around. The data is all the same, prices can vary significantly. Best to spend a few minutes browsing the various sites.

At CraftyClicks our focus is on uptime/availability and keeping the price of PAF data reasonable - at high volumes the price falls to well below 1 penny a click.

Our address lookup web service can be integrated client side via JavaScript or server side via XML.

Let us know your requirements (adam at craftyclicks.co.uk) - you shouldn't be spending anywhere near 40k for this!

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

The base PAF data is the same but a lot of value is put into adding information that is not included into PAF to help with realtime and batch addressing matching with products based on PAF. We have a lot of locality information that is not included within PAF but people tend to use within their address.

As to updates, there are thousands of changes every month so its vital that you use a source that has regular updates to the PAF data and also associated files such as business and consumer names data that also help in the matching process.

Have a look at our site www.capscan.com for both UK and International data quality with services delivered either installed or as a web service.

You can also contact us on 0207 428 1255