# How to get address from postcode

Tags: php, postal-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UK Royal Mail PAF address finder via postcode alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832942/uk-royal-mail-paf-address-finder-via-postcode-alternatives)

I want to implement a functionality of getting the street address from postcode. I'm working in php. So i need a solution to implement in php that will translate postcode to street address. How can i do that?

Comment: Take a look at the royalmail PAF system

Comment: What countries do you need to support?

Comment: Or look at at Ordnance Survey's Open CodePoint

Comment: You will need to call a 3rd party web service to perform the lookup. If you are in the UK, the Roayal Mail PAF is likely the most accurate, but not the cheapest.

Comment: @MarkBaker codepoint will give you postcode -> position, but not postcode -> street address.

Comment: @Rowland - yeah, I forgot as "vanilla" it doesn't do that additional step - I've been using my own extension to the core data to handle street address lookup

Comment: @MarkBaker I thought I was the only nutter to try that one... Have you blogged about how you overcame some of the ambiguity issues?

Comment: @Rowland - takes a nutter to recognise a nutter :) - I don't maintain a blog, but combining the postcode to lat/long with the Open CodePoint gazeteer, I was getting a pretty high accuracy (over 98%) matching to the nearest start/end/midpoint (pity the gazeteer isn't a bit more detailed as a string of nodes rather than simply a 3 point dataset for roads)

Comment: @Rowland - I did propose it as a talk for PHPLondon 2012, but they didn't accept it - but I may try putting it forward for other PHP conferences

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success using the free [Geolite database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite) offered by MaxMind. It comes as CSV and SQLite, both accessible by PHP.

I like this option as it doesn't tie you down to a 3rd party web-service, and they release regular updates with option to auto sync a MySQL version of the database with other existing MySQL installations.

And the uses go far beyond address lookup.

EDIT: to get an actual street address, you "may" need to send the lat-long to another service. GeoLite gives the lat-long of a Postal Code, a street address has a postal code, but postal codes have many street addresses, so that's a harder lookup.

Disclaimer: I'm not in anyway affiliated with MaxMind. Just found it to be a great resource.

Comment: In some locales, a street may have many postal codes, with a postal code only having a single street.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, true. Long streets kinda mess with things don't they? :) At any rate, getting a definitive address from just a postal code isn't an exact science.